# NDF Point a good factor for the discount/premium of future prices

Tags: futures, ndf

I am a bachelor student and I have to do a research paper for my finance class.

I saw that some currency have NDF such as TWD, KRW, BRL. Therefore I imagine that the rate implied in this NDF is what I should use for the pricing of my future as a foreign investor.

I was wondering if there were papers, presentation that showcase the relationship between NDF points and Future, premium/discount and if the former is a good indicator of future cheapnes/richness.

thank you for your help,

Comment: A NDF is essentially identical to a forward. Non deliverable just means it is in a market where there is onshore (domestic) and offshore trading separated due to limitations in capital flow. I think any introductory textbook treats forwards and futures as if they are identical. [Hull](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Futures-Options-Markets-John/dp/8120314638) is commonly used - he also follows that logic.  There are some differences due to daily settlement in futures for example but differences are in many circumstances very small.  You need to be careful with quotation though.

Comment: e.g. [Mini New Taiwan Dollar/US Dollar Futures](https://www.theice.com/products/79696452/Mini-New-Taiwan-Dollar-US-Dollar-Futures) is quoted in the reciprocal of the USDTWD  exchange rate multiplied by 100.